# Matlab Basic Function

Tags: function, matlab

I'm trying to read some matlab code, but I'm new to it.  How do I figure out what the input parameters are?

```
    function [shortly, longly] = lyapunov(signal,timestep,FreqSamp,segmentapproach, duratsegmen, dodivergence)

//lots of code under here but I couldn't find out where signal, timestep, etc come from.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the help for lyapunov. It will tell you that information.

Comment: I mean how do I know where they are coming from.  Are they files?  Or what.  Like I know what types they are supposed to be.  But I just don't understand how it gets the correct info.  If i hit run, it goes.  But like, how does it fetch said info?

Comment: You have supplied ONE line that calls a SINGLE matlab function. Not enough to answer these questions. I think it is time for you to start learning about matlab. There are basic tutorials to be read and followed.

Comment: Could you link me to one that might help with this?

Comment: You are trying to run before you can even walk, before you are even crawling. Start at the beginning.

Comment: While I agree that a crash course in matlab is a good start, I think the question has to do with the code of a function (perhaps in it's own m-file) itself, not how to call the function from somewhere else.  In which case, the function is loading/using default values which would be coded into the unshown code itself somewhere.

Comment: Yeah its a custom .m file.  :P

Comment: Yes, read the help. To be specific, type in 'doc lyapunov' or 'edit lyapunov' to see the source. Of course you have to know the theory of the problem that the lyapunov function is supposed to solve, which is not matlab specific.